# Segmented multiple regression in SAS

Tags: sas, regression, piecewise

I would like to do a segmented multiple regression with fixed effects (with and without interactions). Does SAS has any procedures to handle this task. I've read the PROC NLIN can do a segmented regression, however I can only find tutorials on a segmented regression on a single predictor. I'll be very appreciate if you could point to me any samples on the issue. Links to tutorials would be nice too.

I'm currently working with SAS EG 6.1.

Many thanks,

Mai

Comment: You might want to mention your SAS version (not your EG version), as that's the limiting factor in what you can run.  Since you say 6.1, I assume that version 9.4 is what you're running, but you should verify.

Comment: Yes, Joe. My SAS EG is running on the 9.4 SAS Base.